# Javascript Regex multiline not working

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

Given the code:

```
var regExGroup = new RegExp("\\[group(.*)\\][\s\S]*\\[/group]", 'gi');
var regExResGroup;
while ((regExResGroup = regExGroup.exec(result)) !== null) {
    console.log(regExResGroup[0]);
}
```

And the test data (the value of `result`):

```
[comment]This is a comment[/comment][group title="This" description="That"]
[comment]This is a comment[/comment]
[event]
[condition object="Touch"]On touch[/condition]
[condition object="Touch"]On touch[/condition]
[action object="Sprite"]Destroy[/action]
[action object="Sprite"]Destroy[/action]
[comment]This is a comment[/comment]
[event]
[condition object="Touch"]On touch[/condition]
[condition object="Touch"]On touch[/condition]
[action object="Sprite"]Destroy[/action]
[action object="Sprite"]Destroy[/action]
[/event]
[/event]
[group title="This" description="That"]
[event]
[condition object="Touch"]On touch[/condition]
[condition object="Touch"]On touch[/condition]
[action object="Sprite"]Destroy[/action]
[action object="Sprite"]Destroy[/action]
[event]
[condition object="Touch"]On touch[/condition]
[condition object="Touch"]On touch[/condition]
[action object="Sprite"]Destroy[/action]
[action object="Sprite"]Destroy[/action]
[/event]
[/event]
[/group]
[/group]
```

Why is no match being found?

Comment: `\[group[^\]]*\][\s\S]*\[/group]` works for me. Do note: this will *not* work as intended for nested `[group]` tags. You would need to write a parser for that.

Comment: It should have matched something, but because of double quote rules in your string, `[\s\S]` is seen by the engine as `[sS]`, try `[\\s\\S]`. Also note that you should use `*?` lazy quantifier, or it matches too much.

Answer (score 0):

Multiline is `m`, not `g`. `g` is for global, to match all instances of the regular expression. Otherwise it would only match **once**.

```
new RegExp("\\[group(.*)\\][\s\S]*\\[/group]", 'gim');
```

Comment: Adding the `m` flag makes no difference, still no matches

Comment: Alright, let me look into this. Hold a sec. Thanks for the edit Menixator.

Comment: The problem here is that JavaScript does not have a flag to make the dot (`.`) character match new lines (`\r` and `\n`). I was trying to replace the `\r\n` in a JSFiddle test, but it didn't take effect. We could try a little **brute force** method, if you may.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try one of these quoting/delimiter options

```
 #  (?s)\[group(.*?)\].*?\[/group\]
 # /(?s)\[group(.*?)\].*?\[\/group\]/
 # '/(?s)\[group(.*?)\].*?\[\/group\]/'
 # "(?s)\\[group(.*?)\\].*?\\[/group\\]"
 # 

 (?s)
 \[group
 ( .*? )
 \]
 .*? 
 \[/group\]
```